# Cannot Open VRT of Sentinel2 image created by AutoCreateWarpedVRT

Tags: gdal, gdal-python-binding

I am trying to create a warped VirtualRaster of a Sentinel2 image. Here the Python code I tried:

```
from osgeo import gdal, osr

srs = osr.SpatialReference()
srs.SetFromUserInput('EPSG:32632')

gdal.UseExceptions()
d = gdal.Open('SENTINEL2_L1C:S2A_OPER_MTD_SAFL1C_PDMC_20160506T205836_R122_V20160506T100527_20160506T100527.xml:10m:EPSG_32632')
vrt = gdal.AutoCreateWarpedVRT(d, None, srs.ExportToWkt())
gdal.GetDriverByName('VRT').CreateCopy('test.vrt', vrt)
```

The `AutoCreateWarpedVRT` command actually succeedes, i.e. the returned dataset can be effectively used to read data and metadata.

The problem arises with the last command, which raises the following exception:

```
RuntimeError: No such file or directory
```

Please notice that:

- The `test.vrt` file is actually created and filled, but `gdal.Open` raises the very same error as above (I suspect that the error raised by `CreateCopy` is actually raised by an internal `gdal.Open`)
- If I inject some error in the XML, `gdal.Open`raises a different exception, which is actually related to the injected error.
- `gdalinfo`, `gdal_translate` and QGIS can successfully read `test.vrt`.
- The procedure does work as expected if, instead of a SENTINEL2 image, I use LANDSAT8 (i.e. plain GeoTIFF) data.

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 with GDAL-2.1.0 compiled by myself with the flags `--with-dods-root=/usr --with-ogdi=no` (of course, `gdalinfo`, `gdal_translate` and QGIS are also compiled and ran with the same build).

Comment: I got no error with sentinel L2A and gdal 2.4.3.